# Meaning of "an dem beschriebenen landestypischen Un-Charme"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

From *Der Spiegel*:

> Die Bahnhöfe waren schmutzig, das Westberliner Pflaster war nicht anders als das von mir bislang betretene. Der Berliner Tonfall hinterließ nicht den Eindruck, dass 28 Jahre **an dem bereits von Theodor Fontane beschriebenen landestypischen Un-Charme** irgendetwas geändert hätten. Ein Leben im zweifellos freieren Teil der Stadt war kein Garant für gute Laune.

What does the text in bold mean? I understand that the rest of the sentence means

> The Berlin tone did not leave the impression that 28 years had changed anything.

But what is the "beschriebenen landestypischen Un-Charme"? And why is the preposition "an" used here?

Comment: The prepositional construction is "an dem [...] Un-Charme [...] geändert". It's just spread out really far via embedded phrases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a somewhat difficult sentence. The key phrase is *daran etwas ändern* (change it, make changes to it), in this case *an dem Un-Charme* (a made-up word to denote the opposite of charm). This only leaves *landestypisch* (typical of the country, in this case Berlin) and *bereits von Theodor Fontane beschrieben* (already described by Fontane, a famous author and Berliner who died in 1898.)

To put it all together:

> ... did not give the impression that 28 years had changed anything in the typically Berlin non-charm already described by Theodor Fontane.